# How block user action on zk processing?

Tags: zk

I'm using zk 7.0.3

I have some long process on my application, I want to block user action when a long process is on. I try to use this, but is not working:

```
<device-config>
    <!-- Configure the progress message to show in the center -->
    <device-type>ajax</device-type>
    <embed><![CDATA[
    <script type="text/javascript">
        AU_progressbar = function (id, msg) 
        {
            Boot_progressbox(id, msg, 0, 0, true, true);
        };
    </script>
]]></embed>
</device-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this guide - [Long Operations](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Long_Operations/Use_Echo_Events)

For example, 

`Clients.showBusy("Execute..."); //show a busy message to user`

Answer (score 0):

Create a JS file in your project like MyFile.js and add below code inside this JS

```
zk.procDelay = 100;
if (!zUtl.oldProgressbox) {
 zUtl.oldProgressbox = zUtl.progressbox;
 zUtl.progressbox = function(id, msg, mask, icon, _opts) {
  if(getCookie("language")=="fr_ca") {
   zUtl.oldProgressbox(id, "Traitement de votre demande, s'il vous plaît patienter ...", true, icon, _opts);
  } else {
   zUtl.oldProgressbox(id, 'You can add any text here...', true, icon, _opts);
  }
 }
}
```

Add this `{fileName}.js` into the `lang-addon.xml` file something like given below

```
<javascript src="/resource/js/fileName.js" />
```